# Comparing 2 excel sheet with common key

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare to excel sheets with data 40000 rows and 35 columns.
There is common key in column A but data in both sheets are not same like.

in sheets 1 there may be

```
A
B
C
D
```

and in sheet2 there may be

```
A
C
D
E
```

So I want to compare both and provide the difference in summary sheet.
I have written code but don't know how to complete it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare_Two_Excel_Files_Highlight_Differences()
    'Define Object for Excel Workbooks to Compare
    Dim sh As Integer, ShName As String, lColIdx As Long, sIdx As Long, ssh As String
    Dim F1_Workbook As Workbook, F2_Workbook As Workbook, statmsg As String, trialcnt As Long
    Dim iRow As Double, iCol As Double, iRow_Max As Double, iCol_Max As Double
    Dim File1_Path As String, File2_Path As String, F1_Data As String, F2_Data As String, Header As String


    'Assign the Workbook File Name along with its Path
    File1_Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(2, 2)
    File2_Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(3, 2)
    iRow_Max = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(4, 2)
    iCol_Max = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(5, 2)
    lColIdx = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(6, 2).Interior.ColorIndex

    'Open Files To Compare
    Set F2_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(File2_Path)
    Set F1_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(File1_Path)

'    Windows("File1_Path.xlsx").Activate
'    Columns("A:A").Select
'    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
'    Range("A1").Select
'    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Key"
'    Range("A2").Select
'    Windows("File2_Path.xlsx").Activate
'    Columns("A:A").Select
'    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
'    Range("A1").Select
'    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Key"
'    Range("A2").Select


    'With F1_Workbook object, now it is possible to pull any data from it
    'Read Data From Each Sheets of Both Excel Files & Compare Data
    sIdx = 1
'   trialcnt = 1
    Header = 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells.Clear
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 3) = F1_Workbook.Name
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 4) = F2_Workbook.Name
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Activate
    statmsg = Application.StatusBar
    For sh = 1 To F1_Workbook.Sheets.Count
        ShName = F1_Workbook.Sheets(sh).Name
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(7 + sh, 1) = ShName
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(7 + sh, 2) = "Identical Sheets"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(7 + sh, 2).Interior.Color = vbWhite
        Application.StatusBar = statmsg & " ,Processing Sheet: " & ssh

    '    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(4, 2) = 0 Then iRow_Max = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    '    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(5, 2) = 0 Then iCol_Max = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    '    For iRow = 1 To iRow_Max
    '    For iCol = 1 To iCol_Max
    '        F1_Data = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(iRow, iCol)
    '        F2_Data = F2_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(iRow, iCol)


        'Compare Data From Excel Sheets & Highlight the Mismatches
        '   Find row number

        Dim Row As Long
        Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(4, 2).Value

        On Error Resume Next
        Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(i, 1).Value, F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Range("A1:A200"), 0)


        On Error GoTo 0

        If lRow > 0 Then
        'code


'        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(4, 2) = 0 Then iRow_Max = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
'        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(5, 2) = 0 Then iCol_Max = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
'        For iRow = 1 To iRow_Max
'        For iCol = 1 To iCol_Max


        F1_Data = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(i, iCol)
        F2_Data = F2_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(Row, iCol)


            If F1_Data <> F2_Data Then
  '             F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = lColIdx
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(7 + sh, 2) = "Mismatch Found"
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(7 + sh, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = lColIdx
                If ssh <> F1_Workbook.Sheets(sh).Name Then
                    sIdx = sIdx + 1
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 3) = F1_Workbook.Sheets(sh).Name
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 4) = F2_Workbook.Sheets(sh).Name
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 1) = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(1, 1).Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 2) = "Field"
                    ssh = F1_Workbook.Sheets(sh).Name

                End If
                sIdx = sIdx + 1
            '   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 1) = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(iRow, iCol).Address
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 2) = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(Header, iCol).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 1) = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(iRow, 1).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 3) = F1_Data
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 4) = F2_Data
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 2).Select
            End If
   '     Next iCol


        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(7 + sh, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(7 + sh, 2) & " (" & iRow_Max & "-Rows , " & iCol_Max & "-Cols Compared)"
  '  Next sh

    Next i
End If
Trial_Exit:
    '''''Process Completed
    F2_Workbook.Close savechanges:=False
    F1_Workbook.Close savechanges:=True
    Set F2_Workbook = Nothing
    Set F1_Workbook = Nothing
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Activate
    MsgBox "Task Completed"
    Application.StatusBar = statmsg

 '   End With
 '   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Cells(1, 4).Font.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered `VLookUp`?

Comment: you can also try index() with match()

Answer (score 1):

Well, put this together just to show what you can do with match, the result is the position of the result in the list.

[image]

Edit: just to show how the formula changes when dealing with other sheets, ie data lists on sheets 1 and 2 with the match on sheet 3:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike, that might be really helpful but when I have 30000 rows and 40 columns and i want to get the summary in another sheet, will this be useful, if yes then how. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking for code to do this, but if you are using Excel 2013 or later there is an add-on called Inquire that does this for you.  If you go to File > Options > Add-Ins > COM Add-ins > check Inquire.

If you open both worksheets click on the Inquire ribbon and then select compare files.  It will compare the two files and create a new workbook with the results.

There is also a lot of other cool functionality with this tool and you don't need to code anything.

This is the code you could try instead:

```
Sub wsCompare()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsResults As Worksheet
    Dim strKey As String
    Dim lngFindKey As Long
    Dim rngFindKey As Range

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1") 'set this to your first worksheet with data
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2") 'set this to your second worksheet with data
    Set wsResults = Sheets("Sheet3") 'set this to the worksheet with the results in it

    For i = 1 To 4000 'update this to be the first row containing an ID to the last
        strKey = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
        Set rngFindKey = ws2.Range("A:A").Find(WHAT:=strKey)
        lngFindKey = rngFindKey.Row

        For x = 1 To 35
            If x = 1 Then
                wsResults.Range("A" & i).Value = strKey
            Else
                'add code to calc your difference assuming all numerical values do something like this
                wsResults.Range(Cells(i, x)).Value = ws2.Range(Cells(longFindKey, x)).Value - ws1.Range(Cells(i, x)).Value
            End If
        Next x
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance but i checked that it compares cell vs cell and column vs columns but in my case there may be chances that data in row2 in sheet1 is coming at row3 so that tool will show not matching whereas it is there but at different row. Can you suggest something to cater this. Thanks

Comment: Just updated by above answer to include a coded version